# What should I use to store options for a single blog on a network site?

Tags: theme-options, options

When a user signs up they create a blog. I want to let them set an option that is specific to that blog. When they save that option should I use [update_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), `update_user_option()`, `update_blog_option()` or `update_site_option()`? I know **update_site_option()** is out because that is for setting an option across a network. The rest are somewhat ambiguous.

`update_blog_option` seems appropriate but then why is there a `update_user_option`? And is `update_option` updating for the user logged in or is that also network wide?

**Update:**
After some more research, it looks like [update_user_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option) is the most appropriate call.

Quote from that page:

> When multisite is installed, the $global parameter can be used to set
>   the user option for the whole network, instead of just the current
>   site.

Example setting global value (across all network):

```
update_user_option( $user_id, 'key', $value, true );
```

Thus, this call will save the option for the current site of the user. That's what I want. But they said current site. If the user can have more than one blog then `update_blog_option()` may be more appropriate. So the question is, can a user have more than one blog on a network site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is update_blog_option(). This is specific for each blog. If I used get_user_option() it would be different for each user. If I used get_site_option() it would be across all sites on the network.